# RenderMonkey - GLSL light

Tags: glsl, light

I am making a shader in witch i am using a spot light, I am trying some shaders that I´ve found in the Internet before I make my own.
I found this GLSL code:

vec4 final_color =
    (gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient) +
    (gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient);

Does anyone know how can i make this in the RenderMonkey? i know that i cannot use gl_LightSource[0], how can i make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rendermonkey you would need to set variables for the light properties which your shader would use.  such a a vec4 for the light's ambient, diffuse, and specular colors.  Then some vec3 for the vector to the light / position of the light, etc.

Then you can set these variables to be artist variables, and you can edit them 'live' in the artist Editor on the right.

It's a bit awkward, meaning that you either need to adjust your usage of your shader such that you don't rely on the built in gl_ constructs (so you don't need to edit a shader for it to run both in your program and in RM.  Or you need to edit the shaders when you go inbetween.  I prefer the former.